# array not updating in ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, underscore.js

So I'm trying to sort dates from a number of podcast feeds; to do this I'm looping through an array with the podcast link and pushing the dates into a new array and sorting the data in another function.

The issue is that when I log out the dates array it always returns empty.

I've tried to set a when/then(done produces the same results) construct to no success.

Code below:

```
   _.each(data[1], function(value, key){
    var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(value.links);
    feed.load(function(data) {
      var entries = data.feed.entries;
      _.each(entries, function(value, key){
           that.feedDates.push(value.publishedDate);
      });
    });
```

when/then

```
 $.when(_.each(data[1], function(value, key){
        that.whenAjax(value, key); //a function call to the above
  })).then(function(data){
        //data comes back as the feed links
      that.sortDate(that.feedDates); //date sort function 

 });
```

Thank you
-art

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is down to `.when` not actually knowing `whenAjax` has finished as `feed.load` does not return a promise.

You can fake this and have your function as so:

```
function whenAjax() {
var d = $.Deferred();

_.each(data[1], function(value, key){
    var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(value.links);
    feed.load(function(data) {
      var entries = data.feed.entries;
      _.each(entries, function(value, key){
           that.feedDates.push(value.publishedDate);
      });

      return d.resolve();
    });
}
```

Comment: Had to mod it a bit, but got it to work. Thank you, sir.